# i am trying to implement a common interface using two bean class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

Recently i am practicing Spring AOP. For solving above issue i am trying to use AOP " Introductions - Adding functionality with Aspect" concepts in my code i am using two bean class which is called "Blender & Fan" this two bean implement a common interface which name is "IMachine.java" this interface implement by another class which name is "MachineWear.java" but when i run my App.java class i am getting below Exception.How can i solve it??

> May 09, 2016 2:11:27 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>   INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@c4437c4: startup date [Mon May 09 14:11:27 BDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   May 09, 2016 2:11:28 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/mir00r/spring/aop/beans.xml]
>
> May 09, 2016 2:11:29 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
>   INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@66a3ffec: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,blender,camera,car,fan,logger,machineAspects,lens,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9 cannot be cast to com.mir00r.spring.aop.IMachine
>       at com.mir00r.spring.aop.App.main(App.java:44)

Hare is my Source code

/SpringAOP/src/com/mir00r/spring/aop/App.java

```
package com.mir00r.spring.aop;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/mir00r/spring/aop/beans.xml");

         IBlender blender = (IBlender)context.getBean("blender");
         ( (IMachine) blender).Start();
         blender.Blend();

         IFan fan = (IFan) context.getBean("fan");
         ( (IMachine) fan).Start();
         fan.Active(3);

         context.close();
    }   
}
```

/SpringAOP/src/com/mir00r/spring/aop/MachineAspects.java

```
package com.mir00r.spring.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclareParents;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class MachineAspects {
    @DeclareParents( value = "com.mir00r,spring.aop.*", defaultImpl = com.mir00r.spring.aop.MachineWear.class )
    private IMachine machine;

    @Around("within(com.mir00r.spring.aop.*)")
    public void RunMachine( ProceedingJoinPoint jp ){
        System.out.println("Running........");

        try {
            jp.proceed();
        } 
        catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(".....Completed");
    }
}
```

/SpringAOP/src/com/mir00r/spring/aop/beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mir00r.spring.aop"></context:component-scan>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false"></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
</beans>
```

/SpringAOP/src/com/mir00r/spring/aop/Blender.java

```
package com.mir00r.spring.aop;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Blender implements IBlender {
    /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see com.mir00r.spring.aop.IBlender#Blend()
    */
    @Override
    public void Blend (){
        System.out.println("Blending........");
    }
}
```

/SpringAOP/src/com/mir00r/spring/aop/IBlender.java

```
package com.mir00r.spring.aop;

public interface IBlender {
    public abstract void Blend();
}
```

/SpringAOP/src/com/mir00r/spring/aop/Fan.java

```
package com.mir00r.spring.aop;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Fan implements IFan  {
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.mir00r.spring.aop.IFan#Active(int)
    */
    @Override
    public void Active ( int level ){
        System.out.println("Fan Running level is: " + level);
    }
}
```

/SpringAOP/src/com/mir00r/spring/aop/IFan.java

```
package com.mir00r.spring.aop;

public interface IFan {
    public abstract void Active(int level);
}
```

/SpringAOP/src/com/mir00r/spring/aop/MachineWear.java

```
package com.mir00r.spring.aop;

public class MachineWear implements IMachine {
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.mir00r.spring.aop.IMachine#Star()
    */
    @Override
    public void Start (){
        System.out.println("Machine is Starting........");
    }
}
```

/SpringAOP/src/com/mir00r/spring/aop/IMachine.java

```
package com.mir00r.spring.aop;

public interface IMachine {
    public void Start();
}
```

Comment: If this code is your actual code your `@DeclareParent`s `value` attribute is wrong. `value = "com.mir00r,spring.aop.*"` it contains a `,` instead of `.`.

Comment: thnx M. Deinum now it's working properly ... it was my writing mistake. but i can't find it.. thnx again